Extract the text in a document from iOS device camera without capturing the image or user interaction
Is there any way we can extract the text from a document using the device camera from our iOS mobile app without capturing the image or user interaction.
I'm trying to extract the text from a document using iOS device camera from my app. I'm able to do it by clicking the capture button and processing the image captured.
